# In objective-C, I have a NSString with one letter in it. How can I get the ASCII value of that letter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, ascii

for example:

```
NSString *foo = @"a";
```

How can I get the ASCII value of this? (I know it is really 97, but how can I get it using Objective-C?)

I guess I can convert it to char but I had no luck with that so far. Sorry for being too nooby!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this (untested code)

```
NSString *field = @"s";

unichar c = [field characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"decimal char %d", c);
```

and vice versa

```
unichar asciiChar = 65; // the character A; can also be written like 'A' or 0x0041
NSString *stringWithAsciiChar = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&asciiChar length:1];
```

hope it helps

regards

Comment: While usually correct, this doesn't work too well with multi-byte languages (UTF16 and above encodings).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the character at a certain index using `NSString`'s [characterAtIndex](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:). The result is a `unichar` which is an `unsigned short`. You can probably use this as the ASCII value by casting, although it is a unicode character.